# Simple but elusive expression

Tags: regex, grep

I feel even shy of asking this here but it took already more time than it should.

Say I have these four files:

```
IPCDR_ARB06067956VPLUS_T_201103
IPCDR_ARB06067957VPLUS_T_201103
IPCDR_MOV_ARB06067959VPLUS_T_20110
MOV_CDRARB06067959VPLUS_T_201103
```

I want to grep for only those starting with `IPCDR_MOV` and `MOV_CDR`.

First thing off was:

```
ls -1 | grep "^IPCDR_MOV|^MOV_CDR"
```

but didn't work.

I've done plenty of dumb tests (which I wont bother you with) and nothing comes out. Can someone please put me out of my pain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `-E` switch for using extended regex.

```
$ ls -1 | grep -E "^IPCDR_MOV|^MOV_CDR"
IPCDR_MOV_ARB06067959VPLUS_T_20110
MOV_CDRARB06067959VPLUS_T_201103
```

Comment: good stuff.. I actually tried the ``-e``. for some reason I had it stuck in my mind it was the extended flag (instead of ``-E``). The ``man`` page agrees with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `egrep` instead of `grep`. Otherwise it's a literal string instead of a pattern.